# I made some code for homework, but I don't believe it works. It's code for the Josephus problem

Tags: java, optimization

Here are the rules for the problem that I need for homework:

n people are standing in a circle. Starting from person #1, every 2nd person is executed. this is repeated until the last person is alive, and we return his position in the circle.

For example, for:

- n = 1, 1 is the last person.
- n = 2, 1 is the last person.
- n = 3, 3 is the last person.
- n = 4, 1 is the last person.
- n = 5, 3 is the last person.
- n = 6, 5 is the last person.
  Here's a link to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) page in case I explained it wrong.

This is my Java code for problem.

```java
//Question 4

int num4 = MyConsole.readInt("Please enter a Number(integer) of people which you want me to test what is the safe spot in a Josephus problem: ");
int reducer = 1;
int c = 1;
while (num4 > reducer+1){
    num4 -= reducer;
    reducer += c++;
}
num4 = 1 + (num4-1)*2;
MyConsole.printPrompt("The Safe spot for the entered number is " + Integer.toString(num4));
```

This code as far as I can tell isn't working as intended.
for inputs 1 to 15, it seems to work as intended. however at input 16, I get the answer 3, when it's supposed to be 1. and all answers after that become incorrect as far as I can tell.
Can you please tell me what is wrong with the code?

I want to use this code if possible because it is for homework and so original work is worth more than better/more efficient code. That's why I don't want to use, for example, the Bit shifting solution. I didn't think of it myself.

Comment: Well, compile and run your code, and test if it does the right thing. It doesn't even compile, so no, it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, one moment. I posted it wrong. I'll post the original(I edited it because I used a class called MyConsole.java given by the teacher to the class. It wasn't originally in a function).

Comment: Take more than one moment. Compile and run the code by yourself, with various inputs, and check that the output you get is the expected one. No need to ask us, at least not before you have done that.

Comment: That's the thing, I've done that. It doesn't see to work for all answers I've done. as far as I can tell (unless I made a mistake) it works properly until 20. where it returns an incorrect answer.

Comment: Then change your question, and ask that. Your question should be worded as: "I have tried to solve the Josephus problem. Here's what the Josephus problem is : <explanation, because we have no idea>. I've tested with inputs from 1 to 20, and the output is what I expected. However, for the inputs X, Y and Z, I get A, B and C as output instead of D, E and F. Can you please explain what is wrong with my code?"

Comment: I'll do that right now. Thank you for being very helpful!

Comment: Have you tried debugging through the code? At what point does it not behave as you expect it to? Have you tried writing down what you expect to happen on paper?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, In particular JB Nizet for helping me write my question better. I figured out why my code wasn't working. I was right when I said it's probably flawed by design. When I wrote it on paper, I miscounted and created my formula based on a flaw.

Essentially, I wrote 1,2,4,7. and assumed it was true for the rest of the sequence. I miscounted. It was supposed to be 1,2,4,8. In other words, Multiples of 2.
This is the new code.

```
//Question 4
        int num4 = MyConsole.readInt("Please enter a Number(integer) of people which you want me to test what is the safe spot in a Josephus problem: ");
        int reducer = 1;
        while (num4 > reducer){
            num4 -= reducer;
            reducer *= 2;
        }
        num4 = 1 + (num4-1)*2;
        MyConsole.printPrompt("The Safe spot for the entered number is " + Integer.toString(num4));
```